# best way for storing (not logging) REST error messages in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api2, http-error

Suppose we have an ASP.Net Web API server and all of errors we return to the clients include these properties :

- Error code (REST custom error code)
- HTTP Status (HTTP standard code)
- Error Message (error summery)
- Error Detail (optional)

I just would like to know the best way for storing these error messages (not logging), so later retrieve and return it to clients (via JSON) in case of exception.
Several suggested answers:

- resource file (.resx)
- database
- inside code

Comment: What do you mean by "storing"? you need to log errors, you need to output them to clients. Do you mean to set up error message wording and fetch them for different occasions?

Comment: @trailmax Updated my question.

Comment: use elmah  ------------

Comment: @CuongLe I mentioned not logging. just need good solution for storing the errors message itself. logging is recording events that occur, but I'm asking about storage a different possible events not their occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

If you have taken care of logging it properly then storing them in code is always faster rather than fetching from any datastore.

Some advantages of storing in resx and models for custom error codes in code.

1. Error strings can be in the resx, advantage is they can be localized and will be faster to fetch compared to a db lookup.
2. In API world usually you will return some HttpStatus code for failures or success, the example you mentioned will be something just part of error response. This error response is  based on the logic of the code and hence **ErrorCode to be returned to customer can be a constants mapped to httpstatuscode concatenated with error strings**.

Comment: First I'm including HTTP status code on purpose so that the developer can “see” it without having to analyze the response’s header. Second .resx files are only limited columns Name, Value, and Comment that are not enough for my message model properties.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to log them? The two leading ways of doing that are:

1. Log to CSV file
2. Log to database

Those are considered best practices. Pros for CSV is that they're cheap. Cons for CSV is that they can be hard to query/filter afterwards, especially if you log to separate files.

In database, the pros is the filtering ability, but con is that it is expensive.

Comment: No. I meant where to store the errors info. Not logging them after they happened.

Comment: @BehzadBahmanyar You'll have to rephrase your question - what do you mean by "store" then? In API `response` to clients' `requests` ?

Comment: lets say we want to return to a client an error like this: error code:1023, message:invalid resource id, detail: cannot find book with id {0}. where should I get above info? which bring us to the first question where did I store it? I mean should I store in db, .resx file or another storage option?

Comment: @BehzadBahmanyar Understood. Modified question to add more detail.